# How to go about writing a Javascript pre-loader?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, preloader

I'm not talking about how to [pre-load images using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3358441/how-to-build-a-javascript-preloader-for-images), I am thinking more along the lines of a Flash preloader which displays some sort of feedback while the SWF loads.

The site in question has heavy Javascript usage and requires many large images at page load so I wish to hide the site behind a loading screen till the initial images are all loaded.

Comment: You should write a Flash preloader in (surprise!) Flash :)

Comment: @David Obviously. But I'm not looking for a Flash preloader, I'm trying to write one in JS for a Flash-free website.

Comment: Ahh, I get it. I was confuzzled. Sorry.

Comment: Do you use jQuery? If you do, my plugin, [waitForImages](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages) does that.

Comment: @alex: We do, and it looks like it could definitely do what we need, so good job! One question though, does that handle CSS background images and such as well, or only `<img>` tags?

Comment: @Matthew I added it as an answer :) At the moment it only supports `img` elements, though I may have it doing `background-image` tonight (if I have some time) :)

Comment: @alex: I'm happy to contribute that patch too if you'd rather, I've looked at the code and it's not terribly complex.

Comment: @Matthew Sure, if you'd like to :) Feel free to [contact me](http://www.alexanderdickson.com/contact/) to discuss anything.

Comment: @alex It'll be a week or two till I get to it though, I'm doing preemptive research at the moment.

Comment: @Matthew I'll post a follow up here if I get around to the new feature (or I see you are following the project now too, cheers).

Comment: @Matthew I just pushed my new version which supports image references in the CSS. Let me know what you think :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a [jQuery plugin called waitForImages](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages) that lets you do this.

The callbacks allow you to do whatever when each image has loaded...

```
$('body').waitForImages(
function() {
   // Called when all images have loaded.
},
function(loaded, total, success) {
   // Called once each individual image has loaded.
   // `loaded` is the number of images loaded so far.
   // `total` is the total number of images to load.
   // `success` is `true` if the image loaded and `false` if the image failed to load.
   // `this` points to the native DOM `img` element.
},
// Set the third argument to `true` if you'd like the plugin to look in the CSS
// for references to images.
true
);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/3DfGP/).

Answer (score 0):

I have one written when I first learned JavaScript. I'm going to try to find it in a second. The basic idea is to have a hidden element that's outside the page, and load your image in there.

Beware, ugly code as I wrote this when i started. Also it probably is not exactly what you're looking for, though there are good comments. Just modify it and make it a generic function.  Based on jQuery, for a javascript gallery:

```
this.preload = function(){
    /*
     * Preloads all the image to a hidden div so the animation won't glitch.
     */
    if (document.getElementById("preload")){                // Checks for existance.
        var preload = document.getElementById("preload");   // Gets the preload div if it exists.
    } else {
        var preload = document.createElement("preload");    // Creates the preload div if it doesn't exist.
        $(preload).attr("id", "preload");
    }
    for (var i=0; i<this.aNodes.length; i++){               // Get all the image links
        var img = document.createElement("img");            // Loads all the image in a hidden div.
        $(img).attr("src", this.aNodes[i].href);
        preload.appendChild(img);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you tell when it's completed loading though? I haven't done too much research into this, but I wasn't aware you could hook into that.

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe for the above, you can add something to img.onload where it would notify somewhere that image x has been loaded. Once all your desired images are loaded, you can then emit an all ready signal.