# Show a BLOB image PHP MySQL along with other data

Tags: php, mysql, blob

I have some data stored in a `MySQL` database .. i would like to show the stored image data **along with other** data in a `.php` page..

if i fetch data from the database and use `header("Content-type: image/jpeg");` its not possible to show the image with other php data.. is there a a other way ?

Comment: Browsers request images as separate resources so you need a different "page" to handle the image request.

Comment: simply u say to us AJAX?

Comment: You are familiar with HTML, right? `<img src="image_fetcher.php?id=12345" />` where image_fetcher.php looks up the BLOB and then returns the correct header and data

Comment: i agree with @Joe Philllips ... you need to do in the way he is telling.  and if u can let us know how ur code looks ..we can help

Answer (score 4):

If you set the header to image/jpeg that treats your entire page as an image file.. You want the data to be insert into the image holder only.

Try something like this

```
<img alt="Embedded Image" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIA..." />
```

Where you will next echo the blob data into the image src

```
 <img alt="Embedded Image" src="data:image/png;base64,<?php echo $image->blob_data; ?> "/>
```

Comment: Interesting approach. I'll have to remember this one.

Comment: Matt -- how else would you? Not being condescending, rather I didn't know there was another approach? What else can be done here if he's streaming data into an image dynamically?

Comment: @Atticus The way I would have approached the problem is as recommended in the comments in the question, create a different script that returns the image, then use a `src="get_picture.php?id=blah"` to fetch the image into the page. Wasn't aware of data URI's before just now.

Comment: Oh that'd be a good approach too -- so get_picture.php?id=blah would echo out the data and set its header to an image file.. so that'd work, probably much cleaner that way too.. +1 :)

Comment: @Atticus: No. As long as he's only returning the image data and not a HTML page as well, PHP can return a correct `Content-Type` header for the image data and the browser won't care one bit whether it's generated by PHP or retrieved from the file system. The same sort of tricks are used to generate dynamic images via eg. GD.

Comment: @Atticus a simple test is the following: `header('Content-Type: image/png'); echo file_get_contents('some.png');`

Comment: Yeah no i get that, i use that for a thumbnail generator

Comment: @Atticus Sorry, I misread your comment. As a sidenote, if all you have is data that's already base64'd or similar, you can get away with some weird stuff like `Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64`, but I'd recommend you just unencode it on the serverside.

Comment: Yeah I'd normally go with this approach too, i wasn't thinking outside the box when i was watching OP directly put his data into the image -- I actually never have done it this way, just know it's possible. Even my latest project I've done it the way you're describing. I might be a little high right now... ;)

Comment: @Atticus for pages that aren't reloading (ie, AJAX heavy pages), this actually does kind of make some sort of minor sense. Would totally get around the issue in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5877568/how-to-go-about-writing-a-javascript-pre-loader (because the page wouldn't load till all the images had). Of course, that doesn't give the user any feedback other than a very slow page though...

Comment: I didn't realize you could do this. Interesting

Answer (score 2):

It depends how you stored you data, but sometimes you have to convert the data to base64. Try this

```
echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($blob_data) . '"/>
```